# Subscript is invalid because list is empty

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

i am showing up with following in the visual force error I am  checking the list is null or not but still i am showing up the with error "Subscript is invalid because list is empty"

below is my code

```
<apex:repeat var="vw" value="{!WrapperLists}">
    <apex:variable var="j" value="{!j+1}"/>
    <div class="span9 venues-heading-left">
        {{!vw.v.Name }}
        <span>{!vw.v.Location_Title__c}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid venues-content-div">
        <div class="span4 fav-gallery" style="margin:0 !important; "> 
            <c:MultiGalleryComponent
                    value="{!if(vw.Images.size > 0,vw.Images,'')}" 
                    width="520"
                    height="345"
                    frame="false"
                    gid="o{!vw.v.id}{!Round(j,0)}"
                    ></c:MultiGalleryComponent>
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

can i know how to handle the above error inside a repeat

Comment: how are you checking if the list is not empty. Can you post the code behind the list the page is complaining about?

Comment: `apex:repeat` will handle an empty list fine. Hopefully you are initializing your `j` somewhere before this loop. `if(vw.Images.size > 0,vw.Images,'')`looks invalid. But it doesn't look like you posted Visualforce or Apex where the error comes from.